# open five firefox in same machine - selenium grid

Tags: java, selenium, firefox, selenium-webdriver, selenium-grid

I'm looking confirmation before proceeding parallel test, I try to run selenium test case on 5 firefox browser on same machine, right now it is create only single browser.

Below one is my node creation command.

```
 java -Dwebdriver.firefox.marionette="/u01/driver/geckodriver" -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.0.1.jar -role webdriver -hub http://192.168.1.106:4444/grid/register -port 5566 -host 192.168.1.40 -browser browserName=firefox,version=38.0.1,maxInstances=5,platform=LINUX
```

**maxInstances=5** -> this only enough to make five firefox or I need to write thread class for activate five browser?

Answer (score 0):

Add `maxSession=5` parameter additionally.

`maxInstance` sets max number of instances **of the same browser**, but if your max number of instances (**no matter which browser**) is 1 (`maxSession=1`), then you can't start 5 firefox instances even if you've set `maxInstance=5`.

Comment: do you mean maxInstance & maxSession only enough to make five browser? If yes, I already tried it, it will also create single browser instance. I created my project using maven + testng + seleniumgrid.

Comment: maxInstance & maxSession should make your grid work if your code supports parallel execution, I can't see your code and how you instantiate and use your driver instances.

Comment: yup that was my question buddy. I don't add anything in my code for parallel action in testng. I was expecting above command will do the tricks without alter code but I'm not sure that is why I'm looking your confirmation.

Answer (score 0):

maxInstances and maxSession only not enough to open five browser, we need to write code for parallel test.

> maxInstances=5,maxSession=5

If you use **TestNg** it would be much easier. Below one is my test suit file

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
  <suite name="Suite" parallel="tests">

     <test name="FirefoxTestOne">
     <parameter name="browser" value="firefox" />
        <classes>
           <class name="example.NewTest" />
        </classes>
     </test>
     <test name="FirefoxTestTwo">
     <parameter name="browser" value="firefox" />
        <classes>
           <class name="example.NewTest" />
        </classes>
     </test> 
        <test name="FirefoxTestThree">
     <parameter name="browser" value="firefox" />
        <classes>
           <class name="example.NewTest" />
        </classes>
     </test> 
        <test name="FirefoxTestFour">
     <parameter name="browser" value="firefox" />
        <classes>
           <class name="example.NewTest" />
        </classes>
     </test> 
        <test name="FirefoxTestFive">
     <parameter name="browser" value="firefox" />
        <classes>
           <class name="example.NewTest" />
        </classes>
     </test> 

  </suite>
```

In above file I mention like run my class `example.NewTest` parallely with different test name. When run test suite file it will open five firefox in selenium grid node without session conflict.